# Unregister .deb files

Tags: appmenu

When I install tor browser I used `./start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app` 
How can you undo this? I'm not undoing it I'm just curious. 
edit: typo

Comment: Anything installed can be uninstalled and even purged (also removes user settings). I don't understand the scope of your abstract question.

Comment: I think most of what you are looking for is in the discussion at https://askubuntu.com/questions/348777/how-to-add-tor-browser-to-my-menu-launcher-for-regular-use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`./start-tor-browser.desktop --unregister-app` 
`./start-tor-browser.desktop --help` for more info